# Making an averaging program

Tags: c#, user-interface, average

I am trying to make a program that finds the average of a dynamic number of doubles but I need to reference items from other methods.

```
public int count = 0;
    public double[] nums = new double[1000];
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        label3.Text = "";
    }

    public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        count++;
        string mucho = textBox1.Text;
        nums[count] = Double.Parse(mucho);
        string countstr = Convert.ToString(count);
        label3.Text = countstr;
    }

    public void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        double average = 0;
        int count2 = 0;
        string countstr2 = label3.Text;
        int value = Convert.ToInt32(countstr2);
        while (count2 <= value)
        {
            count2++;
            average = +nums[count2];
        }
        double average2;
        average2 = average / count2;
        string ans = Convert.ToString(average2);
        label2.Text = ans;
    }
```

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: Since you want a dynamic number of doubles, you need List<double> instead of fix length array.

Comment: My problem is that I can't access nums[count2] because the array is set in a different method I can't access

Answer (score 0):

just use a List or write your own average function

```
   private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<double> dynDouble = new List<double>();

        // TODO Cast your array to a List<double>

        double result = dynDouble.Average();
    }
```